# Need help dispalying boolean property state using data binding

Tags: properties, binding, boolean

So i am having trouble trying to get the right data to display in my child form.

I am using the child form to list details about the current object selected in the entry (parent) form.

My issue lies with my Binding object.  I have a boolean property (IsAutomatic) and in the details form i want when it is true, to dispaly "Automatic" and when false "Manual".

I cannot seem to get a string to display to my form, only the word "true" or "false" which in fact is the value, and not what im wanting.

below is the code i've used.

```
   Binding _transmission = new Binding("Text", _formDataSource.Current, "IsAutomatic");
        //how the hell do i do this?
 _transmission.FormatString = string.Format(//and i've tried a ternary operator here to display literals depending on if _transission is true or false, but this is a binding object and not a bool data type.  I attempted to try a cast on the _transmission object, but the IDE did not like it at all.
        lblTransmission.DataBindings.Add(_transmission);
   // do i want code the ternary here 
 (lblTransmission.Text.Equals("true")) ? "Automatic" : "Manual"; //this brought up errors too...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated for i have been on this a while now.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by using a simple cast...

```
Vehicle _vehicle;
```

then later on

```
_vehicle = (Vehicle)_bindingSource.Current;
```

And to get the desired output for my label

```
lblTransmission.DataBindings.Add("Text", _vehicle, "IsAutomatic",true);
lblTransmission.Text = String.Format("{0}", 
( _vehicle.IsAutomatic) ? "Automatic" : "Manual")
```

I hope this winds up helping somebody along the way.  If anyone has suggestions or critiques please feel free to tell me what you think... I'm still just a student ( only 2 terms left !!) .
Thank You.